# Android ImageView stretched

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I try to add ImageViews to a horizontal LinearLayout. They should take up the same space, so I set the weight of these ImageViews to 1. They got laid out as I expect it, but the image got streched. I have the scapeType set to center. 
According to center scaletype, they shouldn't be streched, but they are, and this is my problem. 
My ImageView:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

This is where I add them:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < badges.size() && i < 4; i++) {
                Badge currentBadge = badges.get(i);
                ImageView view = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_badge,
                        mBadgesContainer, false);
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dummy_badge_medic);
                mBadgesContainer.addView(view);
            }
```

The LinearLayout:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_badges"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_badges"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting **background** of `ImageView` and you may have small image in `drawable`

try setting `src`  `view.setImageResource(R.drawable.dummy_badge_medic);`

Comment: OMG. That was just plain dumb.

Answer (score 0):

the property `android:scaleType="centerInside"` is work only for image resource not forthe background.
So try the code given by MAC(https://stackoverflow.com/users/1289716/mac).